# Nokia T20 tablet suddenly refuses to load any TV streaming apps

Tags: video-streaming

I have been having this problem in and out that literally none of my TV streaming apps (specifically Globoplay and LocalNow) are *both* having problems loading any content whatsoever. Google hasn't been helping at all. I have a Nokia T20 tablet, released in 2021(?)
Is there any way I can fix this?

Many thanks,
SaturaniumYT

Extra info: This has been a problem that has been going on in and out since I got this tablet when it ran on Android 11 in December ‘22, now running on Android 12.

Comment: The Nokia tablet is the only problematic device. I also have other non-android devices that work well with one of the apps, Globoplay (the other i never downloaded on those devices)

Comment: I also have a Raspberry Pi 4B running on LineageOS 20 (Android 13) that has both apps, one works fine, the other i have not yet tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142433/discussion-between-saturanium-and-alecxs).

Comment: The play integrity app gave me all green checks